# How to do 3D boid model simulation on Python?

Tags: python, 3d, simulation, modeling, boids

I want to create a 3D Boids Model in Python. I would like to animate the whole thing during runtime and add options to change the parameters. Is there any package which supports such case? I assume matplotlib is not the right choice? I thought about setting up an array with all necessary informations about each boid, and then looping through all boids (changing their parameters) and displaying the change in another frame in the simulation.

Comment: Maybe this is not the sort of answer you are looking for but I just [Googled for the words boids and python](https://www.google.com/search?q=boids+python) and found 217,000 results. That would be a good place to start.

Comment: Yeah, thanks that was the first thing I did as well. I now did a lot of more research. There is not a simple straight forward way to animate it during runtime, however there is a complicated way of doing it through p5, a library coming from java and the python processing library. I now have just done it not in runtime but rather as an animation which gets saved as an mp4. For my case thats enough but when you wnat to do it during runtime it is better to maybe use java. Thanks anyway for you comment! :)